Finding USB's device descriptor (more specifically the bcdUSB) without needing to install additional driver in C#
I am currently a little stumped as where to go next in my current project. First, here is some background.
I am trying to identify the USB version of the attached devices (such as 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, etc), but without needing to install extra drivers. That is to say, I want to be able to plug in any USB, run the code, and know the USB version. I know it should be possible since programs like USBTreeViewer and USBDeviceViewer are able to (albeit in C). I am also not super familiar with the C# language or visual studio thus a thorough as possible answer would be greatly appreciated.
Here is what I have tried or looked into without much success, and I would appreciate any suggestions of where to go next.

Use WMI and the Win32_USBHub class to access USB version field, but that field is usually empty for most USBs
Use LibUsbDotNet, but this requires the USB's to have the libusb-win32 driver. However, this would allow me to access the bcdUSB
Following the microsoft USB device descriptor page, there are a couple of different options listed (Such as UWP app that uses Windows.Devices.Usb or a Win32 desktop app that uses WinUSB functions) but they all seem to require Winusb.sys or some other driver [Although, I could easily be mistaken as I am slightly overwhelmed by all the information]
This one is more of a work around and would work, but I would like to avoid if possible: use a subprocess to open usbview but having it write the results in a text file, and then I can parse the text file finding the information I need.

Once again, I would greatly appreciate any tips, suggestions, or nudges in the right direction.Thank you!

The usbview source code is on GitHub.  I think it might actually talks to the hub driver for each USB hub, and it sends a command to the hub asking it to get descriptors from the device.  You're probably just going to need to translate that to C# line by line and will need to learn how to read C.  Or you could compile a DLL using C and call it from C#.
